# How to get triggers from .nxe files with FieldTrip Toolbox

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to analyse TMS-EEG data from Nexstim with FieldTrip Toolbox. I want to make a trial matrix from my raw .nxe data. But how I know which triggers to assign for cfg.trialdef.eventvalue, when cfg is the output variable. I'm trying to mimic the same kind of code as you can find from the tutorial: http://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/tutorial/tms-eeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution to the problem. With a command event = ft_read_event('filename.nxe') I got a struct with fields: type, value, sample, duration and offset and this is all I need.